# What is the origin of "unterbringen"

Tags: etymology

I would like to know the origins of *unterbringen*. From what words does this word come in old German, what are the links I can make?

Answer (score 3):

According to Grimm (Bd 24) The word comes from 'underbringen' (mhd).

It has had three main meanings:

- nach unten bringen (bring down/below)
- unterwerfen (subdue, bring under)
- unter das Dach bringen (to house, to store)

The examples from Grimm start from the 16th, 16th and 17th century.

Today the third meaning is the only one used.

Its is related to 'onderbringen' (mnl) and 'bringa under' (dän schwed).